# How can I customise event listeners in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm making a basic program that uses a slider to move a rectangle around a page. I can set up the slider using something like

```
<input type = "range" min = "5" max = "500"  value = "5" id = "xvalue" >
```

and then reference the value of the slider with

```
d3.select("#xvalue").on("input", function() {
  update(+this.value, "x");
});
```

where update() is a function to change the position of the rectangle.

The event listener triggers when the value of the slider changes. However, it seems to me as if the event listener also triggers when the "max" and "min" attributes of the slider change.

How can I ensure that the event listener only triggers when the "value" attribute of the input object changes and not any other attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that changing "min" or "max" doesn't trigger the event. For instance, I did just like you:

```
d3.select("#xvalue").on("input", function() {
    console.log("The value is " + this.value);
});
```

And then I created two buttons, one that sets the min value to 30 and other that sets it back to 5:

```
d3.select("#button1").on("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("xvalue").setAttribute("min", 30);
});

d3.select("#button2").on("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("xvalue").setAttribute("min", 5);
});
```

I'm clicking the buttons but it's not triggering the listener, just changing the "min" values. I can see the slider moving when I click one button after the other, but nothing is logged in the console.

Comment: Strange. I followed the debugger in Chrome in my original program and it seemed to suggest that it was triggering the event - the fact that it actually doesn't suggests a deeper problem that I don't fully understand.

While we're on the topic though - do you know how you would set an event listener to trigger when "min" was changed, but to not trigger when "max" was changed?

Comment: I never heard about it... Try this: post a new question, asking specifically about a event listener that trigger when you change min or max (if it exists!), and put the tags "JavaScript" and "html" in your question, but not " d3". Certainly one JavaScript wizard will show up with the answer.

Comment: BTW: *how* are you changing the "min" value? This is important to solve the issue.

Comment: I uploaded my code  (http://bl.ocks.org/puzzler10/ba2be2298ffa7f0fa592e98167c05af9). I wanted to prevent the rectangle moving off the screen - by limiting the maximum values the sliders can take. However, there's a bug with the rectangle going off the screen - to find it, slide the "x" slider all the way to the right, then the "width" slider, and then try moving the "x" slider again. I initially thought this was due to the event handler running twice, once with the value of the attribute and once with updating the maximum.

Comment: How would the method of changing "min" determine how the event handler triggers? I'll make a new question as you suggested, but I'm curious about this too.

Comment: Yes, I see... I'd do it differently to prevent the rectangle moving off the screen: if the user changes width or height, I'd simply get this value and update the slider "max" input, using the `setAttribute` in my exemple above. So, if the user increases the width by 200px, the "max" of x slider would drecrease by 200px. The same to height/y axis. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yep! I've got it. Thanks for your help! I'd upvote your answers, but unfortunately I'm too reputation poor to do so.